# Group and compare the number from string column

Tags: mysql

I have a mysql table which contains alphanumeric content. The number is in the exact format '**/prop/xx/xxx**' so I use 'substring'to extract them. But I need to group and order them from its population by desc.

[image]

So my ideal code like this

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(`page_url`,10,3) as pid from `prop_log` group by pid order by pid
```

I know it's impossible with this code but any advice?

PS. number in **page_url** can be 4 digits or more

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not aggregation function so you should use distinct and not group by

```
 SELECT distinct SUBSTRING(`page_url`,-3) as pid 
  from `prop_log` 
  order by pid
```

and if you need  only the rows with digit

```
 SELECT distinct SUBSTRING(`page_url`,-3) as pid 
  from `prop_log` 
  WHERE `page_url` REGEXP '[0-9]'
  order by pid
```

and for number of rows

```
 SELECT SUBSTRING(`page_url`,-3) as pid 
  from `prop_log` 
  WHERE `page_url` REGEXP '[0-9]'
  group by SUBSTRING(`page_url`,-3)
  order by count(*)
```

Comment: It's near, but how can I get rid off those non-digit value? They're also sorted and not group by the substring population.

Comment: you want filter only the values with 3 digit at the end??

Comment: yeah, but sometimes the number may increse to 4 digits. BTW, I need these values to sort from it's population too.

Comment: if the value is variabile you can locate the last occurrence of / and use this index  for get the string you need .. hope my answer  is at least useful   ..

Comment: Yes, I tested and it's working. But it not sort by the population. Still from the pid. Which is I cannot use it to query the most popular view item.

Comment: what do you mean with 'population' .. i don't see any population column in your code  ..

Comment: I want to do it like this... but it's don't know 'pid'

SELECT SUBSTRING(  `page_url` , -3 ) AS pid, COUNT( pid ) AS nPid
FROM  `prop_log` 
WHERE  `page_url` REGEXP  '[0-9]'
GROUP BY pid
ORDER BY nPid DESC 
LIMIT 0 , 30

Comment: That's what I'm talking about. You saved my day. Thank you.

Comment: Can I asked one more question? Why it's unknown the 'pid' column. SELECT prop_sid,SUBSTRING(`page_url`,-3) as pid 
from `prop_log` 
inner join prop_db2 on prop_db2.prop_id=pid
WHERE `page_url` REGEXP '[0-9]'
group by SUBSTRING(`page_url`,-3)
order by count(*) desc
limit 5

Comment: post your comment in a new question  and comment me the related  link please  .. (I can not read the code well)