# How to inner join a table with the pseudo value

Tags: mysql

According to the solution posted by @scaisEdge [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45519002/1620626). I have a furthur question with 'inner join'. I tried join them with the 'pid' value. But the sql says 'unknown'

Here's his code:

```
 SELECT SUBSTRING(`page_url`,-3) as pid 
  from `prop_log` 
  WHERE `page_url` REGEXP '[0-9]'
  group by SUBSTRING(`page_url`,-3)
  order by count(*)
```

And this is mine:

```
SELECT prop_sid,SUBSTRING(`page_url`,-3) as pid 
from `prop_log` 
inner join prop_db2 on prop_db2.prop_id=pid
WHERE `page_url` REGEXP '[0-9]'
group by SUBSTRING(`page_url`,-3)
order by count(*) desc
limit 5
```

PS. prop_sid is from prop_db2

Comment: i have posted  an aswer  with some others suggestion too  ..  hope is what you are looking for

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use an alias  in a where (or on ) condition

```
SELECT prop_sid,SUBSTRING(`page_url`,-3) as pid 
from `prop_log` 
inner join prop_db2 on prop_db2.prop_id=SUBSTRING(`page_url`,-3)
WHERE `page_url` REGEXP '[0-9]'
group by SUBSTRING(`page_url`,-3)
order by count(*) desc
limit 5
```

the use of alias is allowed in order by and in some mysql version in group by  but not in where  ..

and you should also use a (fake)   aggregation function on column not in group by

```
SELECT min(prop_sid),SUBSTRING(`page_url`,-3) as pid 
from `prop_log` 
inner join prop_db2 on prop_db2.prop_id=SUBSTRING(`page_url`,-3)
WHERE `page_url` REGEXP '[0-9]'
group by SUBSTRING(`page_url`,-3)
order by count(*) desc
limit 5
```

or add the column to your group by  is is coherent with the query

```
SELECT prop_sid,SUBSTRING(`page_url`,-3) as pid 
from `prop_log` 
inner join prop_db2 on prop_db2.prop_id=SUBSTRING(`page_url`,-3)
WHERE `page_url` REGEXP '[0-9]'
group by SUBSTRING(`page_url`,-3), prop_sid
order by count(*) desc
limit 5
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT prop_sid, prop_db2.prop_id as pid 
from `prop_log` 
inner join prop_db2 on prop_db2.prop_id=SUBSTRING(`page_url`,-3)
WHERE `page_url` REGEXP '[0-9]'
group by prop_db2.prop_id
order by count(*) desc
limit 5
```